# Ownership Verification Certificate in Terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform0.12+

I have certificate which is singed by third party (Not AWS issued). I imported this certificate in ACM, and I am trying to set up Api gateway custom domain names that will use this certificate. Since they are not AWS issued I know that I have to select 'Imported or private certificate' in the Endpoint Configuration, and select Ownership Verification Certificate. It is very clear what I should do in the AWS console.
However, the problem appears when I am trying to create the Custom Domain Name by Terraform. It looks like I cannot define 'ownership_verification_certificate_arn' in the aws_api_gateway_domain_name resource. This is what I have:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "example" {

  regional_certificate_arn = var.example_resource_arn

  domain_name     = "example.com"
  security_policy = "TLS_1_2"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }

  ownership_verification_certificate_arn = var.acm_public_certificate_arn

  mutual_tls_authentication {
    
    truststore_uri =  "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.api_gw_truststore[0].bucket}/truststore.pem"
  }

  tags = var.tags
}
```

acm_public_certificate_arn is a certificate issued by ACM that can validate the domain name.
However I got an error "Error: Unsupported argument. An argument named ownership_verification_certificate_arn" is not expected here."

If I remove it I am getting: Error: Error creating API Gateway Domain Name: BadRequestException: Missing ownershipVerificationCertificate. To use an imported or private certificate for the domain name, ownershipVerificationCertificate is required.

FYI, I cannot have the certificate and the key pem files in the terraform code.

I cannot find any solutions or examples. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Anna

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be quoted to start with, i.e., `"var.acm_public_certificate_arn"` should be `var.acm_public_certificate_arn`.

Comment: It was my mistake while typing the code here. I don't have it in my original code. I am still getting an Error: Unsupported argument.

Comment: How about `truststore_uri`, did you specify a valid S3 URI in your code and it's only missing here?

Comment: @MarkoE , the uri is also correct. Sorry I did so many mistakes coping here.